# MDX: How to get rows count

Tags: mdx

How to get the row count in new column, please click the above image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BH8p.png)

```
 WITH MEMBER DimName AS [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
      MEMBER DimKey AS [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
      MEMBER [Measures].[Test]  AS ([Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt] + [Measures].[NrPatientKeyCnt])
      MEMBER RowCount AS COUNT(NONEMPTY([DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].[Health Plan Key]))
SELECT  {[Measures].DimKey ,
         [Measures].DimName,
         [Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt],
         [Measures].[CareProviderPatientCnt],
         [Measures].[PCPPatientCnt], 
         [Measures].[Test],
         RowCount} ON COLUMNS ,
NonEmpty([DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].MEMBERS) ON ROWS 
FROM [PopulationReportCube]
```

Comment: you want it to say 1,2,3.... the top row being 1 the last row being n ?

Comment: I need  total row counts, not sequence. Suppose if result contains 20 rows, i need every row 20,20,20..... in RowCount

Answer (score 3):

Try this - they should all say 6:

```
MEMBER RowCount AS 
   COUNT(NONEMPTY([DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].MEMBERS))
```

But if you want something very dynamic then you'll need to explore the Axis function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145531.aspx

Which could be implemented like this:

```
WITH
SET [Rows] AS 
   {Axis(1)}
MEMBER [Number of rows] AS 
   [Rows].Count 
...
...
```

Comment: can you please see the attached image for result set

Comment: in result set getting only 2 records. so, rowcount is 2,2